# iframe sharing inside facebook

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, iframe, share

I have a jquery script for image spin.This scipt come from an another site.And i showed this using an iframe in my site.I need to share this on facebook.Whene i share this as a post images should rotate ,is any way to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to save the rotated file on your server and then share the link.
For the share-thing you will have to use the Facebook API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

Comment: actually i don't need share button,i could share my page link.is any way to share a iframe in facebook .I mean using meta tags. Answers will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the rotated image to your server and set the content of this meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="" />
```

...to the url of the saved image.

Comment: Also tried that. in the case of image its okay ,but i have a javascript for spinning imags

Comment: Javascript sharing and Iframe sharing supported by facebook?